# plotting geom bars with already counted values using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and i have question about ggplot2. I have four sums and i want to put them on one bar plot. If I use basic barplot it is easy. But for some reason i need to do this with ggplot2 and I dont know how ( I dont how to plot concrete numbers with ggplot). here are output and code of  used basic barplot function http://prntscr.com/f7b7a7

```
    neIzlazakNaKPZ1 <- sum(is.na(eduJosip$KPZ1))
    neIzlazakNaKPZ2 <- sum(is.na(eduJosip$KPZ2))
    neIzlazakNaMI <- sum(is.na(eduJosip$MI))
    neIzlazakNaZI <- sum(is.na(eduJosip$ZI))
    barplot(c(neIzlazakNaKPZ1, neIzlazakNaMI, neIzlazakNaKPZ2, neIzlazakNaZI), main="NE IZLASCI NA ISPITE MAT1 14/15", ylab="BROJ NE IZLAZAKA",  names.arg=c("KPZ1", "MI", "KPZ2","ZI"),border="red", density=c(20, 40, 60, 80))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(neIzlazakNaKPZ1, neIzlazakNaMI, neIzlazakNaKPZ2, neIzlazakNaZI),
                 x = c("KPZ1", "MI", "KPZ2","ZI"))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = 'red')
```